# installing arm-none-eabi-gcc on freebsd 9

Tags: linux, unix, freebsd, compile, arm

I'm trying to follow this guide :

https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/arm/ArndaleBoard

but as you can see here : http://www.montedivenere.it/images/freebsd-arm/freebsd-arndale.png

I need to install arm-none-eabi-gcc on freebsd 9. What should I do here ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It asks for installed precompiled toolchain path. You need to install a precompiled cross compiler toolchain which is why you are getting the error `arm-linux-gcc: not found`. You can get the precompiled CodeSourcery toolchain which is available on the Mentor Graphic's website. Download the toolchain which is compatible to your requirement (architecture).

Comment: There is no toolchain available for freebsd....

Comment: Visit the following link [link](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0155k/BDCDGBBG.html). Read about prefix arm-none-eabi-, which is a prefix of toolchain to be required to cross compile.

Comment: http://ieee.ucsd.edu/wiki/tutorials/how_to_compile_codesourcery_arm_gcc_for_freebsd